# Создать стрим, с помощью которого сделать обратный отсчет от 5 до 0 (Формат сообщения «До запуска 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0. Пуск»

Tags: java, инспекция-кода

Мой уровень начальный. Решение следующее. Просьба оценить.

```
System.out.println("До запуска " + Stream
            .iterate(5, x -> x - 1)
            .limit(5)
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            + ". Пуск");
```

Comment: что конкретно оценить?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Оценить есть ли другие лучшие варианты решения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Другие варианты:

- Генератор с условием [`Stream::iterate(T seed, Predicate<? super T> hasNext, UnaryOperator<T> next)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#iterate-T-java.util.function.Predicate-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-), добавленным в Java 9, тогда можно избавиться от вызова `limit`:

```java
Stream<Integer> from5to1 = Stream.iterate(5, x -> x > 0, x -> x - 1);
String fiveToOne = from5to1
        .map(x -> x.toString())
        .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")); // вместо списка в []
```

- `IntStream::range` + `IntStream::map/IntStream::mapToObj`:

```java
Stream<Integer> from5to1 = IntStream.range(0, 5).map(x -> 5 - x).boxed();

String fiveToOne = IntStream.range(0, 5)
    .mapToObj(x -> Integer.toString(5 - x))
    .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")); // строка цифр, разделённых запятыми
```

- `Stream::generate` + `Stream::limit` и `AtomicInteger::getAndDecrement` для модификации счетчика (используется стрим с состоянием (stateful)):

```java
AtomicInteger n = new AtomicInteger(5);
Stream<Integer> from5to1 = Stream.generate(n::getAndDecrement).limit(5);
```

Вместо атомарного целого можно воспользоваться "ссылочным" значением:

```java
int[] n = {5};
Stream<Integer> from5to1 = Stream.generate(() -> n[0]--).limit(5);
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!